# Highchartsの初期表示の際のアニメーションを変えたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Highchartsでは標準で円グラフのパイが中心から放射状にアニメーションしますが、これを止めたいです。何か方法をご存知ありませんか？

Comment: 恐らく日本の方だと思いますが、ja.stackoverflow.comの方は日本語でokです。本家のstackoverflow.comと間違えてポストされたのではないですか？

Comment: はい。jaの存在を知らず…よく理解していないまま投稿してしまいました。。。

Comment: 標準のアニメーションが「半径が徐々に大きくなる動き」と「畳まれていたグラフが扇状に広がる動き」の組み合わせだと考えた時に、前者だけ無効化したいということですか・・・？

Comment: urarist様　その通りでございます｡　色々調べているのですが､その方法がわからず…単純にanimation offしか探しきれていません｡

Answer (score 1):

初期表示のアニメーションを止めたい、という質問ですね。

それは、[plotOptions.pie.animation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.animation)で制御できます。

ドキュメントに書かれている[Pie chart demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)はアニメーションが有効ですが、上記の`animation=False`の指定を追加した[アニメーション無しdemo](http://jsfiddle.net/znrLt1qt/)を作成しました。
後者は放射状のアニメーションがないと思います。

以下は、追加したオプション指定の抜粋です。

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        〜略〜
        ,
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                animation: false,
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                〜略〜
        },
        〜略〜
    });
});
```

Comment: コメントがかなり遅くなってしまいました｡｡｡　大変申し訳ありません｡　animationをオフだと本当にアニメーションがまったくない状態ですので､要望ではありません｡　ただ､単純にぐるっと一周してくれればいいのですが…

Comment: 初期表示はアニメーションが効いてほしいが、パイを選択したときに値表示や強調表示は止めたい、という意味ですか？そこまで汲み取って回答できる人はいないと思いますよ。
質問を更新して、要望を的確な日本語で書いてください。

Answer (score 0):

> 標準のアニメーションが「半径が徐々に大きくなる動き」と「畳まれていたグラフが扇状に広がる動き」の組み合わせだと考えた時に、前者だけ無効化したい

円グラフのアニメーションは、seriesTypes.pie.prototype.animateメソッドで定義されていますので、このメソッドをオーバライドすることで、アニメーションのカスタマイズが可能です。「半径が徐々に大きくなる動き」だけを無効化する場合は、半径rが0からスタートする処理をコメントアウトしてください。

```
// パイチャートのアニメーションメソッドをオーバライド
Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.animate = function(init) {
    var series = this,
        points = series.points,
        startAngleRad = series.startAngleRad;
    if (!init) {
        Highcharts.each(points, function (point) {
            var graphic = point.graphic,
                args = point.shapeArgs;
            if (graphic) {
                graphic.attr({
                    // スケーリングを無効化
                    //r: point.startR || (series.center[3] / 2),
                    start: startAngleRad,
                    end: startAngleRad
                });
                graphic.animate({
                    // スケーリングを無効化
                    //r: args.r,
                    start: args.start,
                    end: args.end
                }, series.options.animation);
             }
        });
        series.animate = null;
    }
};
```

詳細は、「[円グラフのアニメーションで、スケーリングだけ無効にする](http://highchartsmaniacs.com/2018/11/17/%E5%86%86%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%80%81%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91/)」を参照下さい。